# "Some examples of the Galois correspondence" lecture notes of K.Conrad

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I was reading the [lecture notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorrexamples.pdf) of Prof. Conrad, namely example 5 on the page 7 and ran into the following unclear moment on the page 9:

**Question:** He want to show that $[\mathbb{Q(\alpha+\frac{i}{\alpha}):\mathbb{Q}}]=4$. Suppose it is not $4$ then he claims that this field is inside $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Honestly to say yesterday I've spens alomost a whole day trying to derive it but failed to do it.

Can anyone show how did he get this ?

Would be very grateful for help!

**EDIT:** I can show directly that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\frac{i}{\alpha}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ because $\alpha+\frac{i}{\alpha}$ is a root of polynomial $x^4-2x^2+5$ which is irreducible over rationals. But I would like to understand how the author is doing this. Namely why this extension is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$?

[image]

Comment: You know, it would really help if you told us somewhere what $\alpha$ is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, oh sorry, $\alpha=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{5})/2}$

Comment: Good. Now, the other thing we need to know is what $r$ and $s$ are, since evidently the fixed field of $rs$ is of some importance here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, please take a look in my topic. I put the link to the Conrad's lecture

Comment: @GerryMyerson, https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorrexamples.pdf

Comment: I don't want a link to Conrad's lecture. I want you to type in a question with enough information to make it possible for someone to give you an answer. You do want someone to answer, don't you?

Comment: I guess you don't.